How to replicate Stata 'margins at' command to interpret interaction effects using marginaleffects package in R?
I am trying to replicate some Stata code that uses average marginal effects to interpret interaction effects  in R.
Suppose I am using the mtcars dataset to estimate the average miles/gallon mpg of a car as a function of gross horsepower hp that is allowed to vary by the number of cylinders cyl, like below:
mod1 <- lm(mpg ~ hp:as.factor(cyl), data=mtcars)

In Stata, I could calculate the average marginal effects of horsepower at different values of the discrete covariate cyl as follows:
margins, dydx(hp) at(cyl == 4) at(cyl == 6) at(cyl == 8)

I am wondering how I can do this in R, using the marginaleffects package.
I was thinking about using the avg_slopes function with the by statement (as show below), but I'm not sure whether the by statement matches the at statement of the Stata code. I don't really understand the documentation  of the by statement well.
library(marginaleffects)

avg_slopes(mod1, variables=c("hp"), by=c("cyl"))

**Output**
 Term    Contrast cyl Estimate Std. Error      z Pr(>|z|)    S   2.5 %   97.5 %
   hp mean(dY/dX)   4  0.00835     0.0347  0.241   0.8097  0.3 -0.0596  0.07633
   hp mean(dY/dX)   6 -0.04492     0.0248 -1.810   0.0704  3.8 -0.0936  0.00373
   hp mean(dY/dX)   8 -0.04736     0.0135 -3.496   <0.001 11.0 -0.0739 -0.02081


Have you seen this page from the documentation? It uses the same dataset you propose and shows side-by-side comparisons between Stata and marginaleffects: https://marginaleffects.com/vignettes/alternative_software.html#stata

This section in particular seems to be exactly what you want: https://marginaleffects.com/vignettes/alternative_software.html#counterfactual-marginal-effects

@vincent I was not aware of this. Thank you, that solves my issue!

@Flap can you put the relevant section as an answer in case this link is broken in the future?

Thanks to @Vincent I found the answer on this link: https://marginaleffects.com/vignettes/alternative_software.html#counterfactual-marginal-effects
With the at argument, Stata’s margins command estimates average counterfactual marginal effects, which are average marginal effects for particularly interesting (sets of) observations specified in the at argument. It is obtained by duplicating the whole dataset — in this case 3 times — and setting the values of cyl to the three specified values in each of those subsets.
The following code should obtain the same result as the stata code but then using the marginaleffects package in R. By using datagrid() we create a counterfactual dataset in which the full original dataset is replicated for each potential value of the cyl variable
avg_slopes(
    mod1,
    variables = "hp",
    by = "cyl",
    newdata = datagrid(cyl = c(4, 6, 8), grid_type = "counterfactual"))

Output
 Term    Contrast cyl Estimate Std. Error      z Pr(>|z|)    S   2.5 %   97.5 %
   hp mean(dY/dX)   4  0.00835     0.0347  0.241   0.8097  0.3 -0.0596  0.07635
   hp mean(dY/dX)   6 -0.04492     0.0248 -1.810   0.0704  3.8 -0.0936  0.00373
   hp mean(dY/dX)   8 -0.04736     0.0135 -3.496   <0.001 11.1 -0.0739 -0.02081

